# open database connection attacks

Tags: php, exploit

Just learning php and aiming to write quality code.

I read everywhere that you should close all database connections to reduce vulnerability of your system. It's okay, but why and when?

Connections are closed automatically at the end of runtime. So questions are: 
Can anyone please refer to me a resource that explains how an open database connection can actually be exploited? And for how long can it safely be open?
What is the difference if I close it with the last line of my application or leave it for the shotdown handler?

Some worth-reading description on the topic would be welcome.

Comment: Where did you read this: `I read everywhere that you should close all database connections to reduce vulnerability of your system.`

Comment: Head first labs: PHP and MYSQL

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 simple tips that will help improve the security profile of your code, when it comes to databases:

1. Use [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo) or [`mysqli`](http://php.net/mysqli), and don't use `mysql`.
2. Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), always.
3. Never trust user input.

Database connections are not a real worry because:

1. They are automatically discarded at the end of your script, *unless you are using [persistent connections](http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php)*.
2. The database server will not let you hold on to an open connection indefinitely.
3. There is a limit on the database server on how many open connections are allowed. After this limit is exhausted, the database will refuse new connections with an appropriate message to the client.